# How can i get Week (1-52) from Datetime?

Tags: razor

I have been scouring the internet for some time now trying to get the knowledge on how to get the Week (1-52) from Datetime in Razor View Engine.

I have coded PHP before where getting week was an easy task but i really have not found a solution to my problem. Is there a way to get Week out of simple Razor language or do i need to use something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MarcB: the tag wiki suggests it's ASP.NET, not PHP.

Comment: Yeah, shoot... just noticed that. In that case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear.aspx

Comment: I have looked into that link you supplied Marc B but i could not wrap my head around how i actually can get that into Razor and the datetime().

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction after a heavy read up on the classes i have gotten a working code which i will share with you all. Take Note this is for Razor view engine
`System.Globalization.CultureInfo culinfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    var weekNum = culinfo.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now,System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek,DayOfWeek.Monday); @weekNum`